# Angular "TypeError: b is undefined" when using uglify

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, undefined, uglifyjs

I'm using Angular, and as you know, there is Angular "1" (the old version) and Angular 2 (the newest) which include typescript.

This is my problem I've encountered today:
I'm doing an application using angular, so I've created the project folder (project-frontend) and installed locally grunt, with bower I've downloaded the packages for angular.

I've created the gruntfile.js and configured it with these tasks:

```
"grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1"
"grunt-ng-annotate": "^2.0.2"
"grunt-contrib-uglify": "^2.0.2"
```

And with many others, like cssmin, htmlmin etc etc, but the problems occours with these tasks, or, precisely with uglify.

The problem is that if I concat all angular js files (angular.js, angular-rout.js, angular-resource.js ...) and I uglify everything, then, when i deploy my war in a Tomcat, i get this error:

> TypeError: b is undefined

So, what i think that cause the problem is uglify, because I've tried to run the same tasks for another old project, which was having uglify 1.0.1 and everything works, I've also controlled that if I just run concat and ngAnnotate, the final angular files (the one from this project, and the one from the last) are pratically identical.

I don't know if this has to do something with typescript (seeing the error I thinked about that) because I assumed that typescript have been inserted into angular since 2.0.0 versions, and I'm currently working with a 1.5.8 version (I also tried 1.2.9).

I controlled my application code with jshint (it's the first task that i run) and there are no errors prompted in the terminal.

I've also tried to re-configure the tasks taking as example the old project Gruntfile.js file.

I don't know what to do anymore, I'm blocked with this problem and I don't know how to move further, some advices?

Comment: `ngAnnotate` can miss things such as functions in `ui-bootstrap` / `ui-router` which you may need to specifically annotate with an `@ngInject` comment. Can you locate the function with the undefined `b`?

Comment: So, the 'b is undefined' occurs at line 1 with colum 461 (of the minified file) and this is what is typed near there "var f=b.$$minErr("$resource")"

Comment: Ok, finally i founded the error, i was copying in a wrong way the files with concat, surely i was missing a file to create the final angular file :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now that i've found the error, as i writed in the comments under my question, i figured out that concatenating js files like this:

```
src: 'bower_components/**/*.js'
```

Which should concatenate all js files inside folders and subfolders in my bower_components directory, simply don't know why but breaks angular final files, if i write

```
src: ['bower_components/angular/*.js',
      'bower_components/angular-route/*.js',
      'bower_components/angular-resource/*.js']
```

Which points directly to all files that need to be concatenated, everything works in my application with angular concatenated and uglified file

I don't know why there's this issue, beacuse if i print in terminal under my project-frontend folder this command:

```
echo bower_components/**/*.js
```

I can see this output:

```
bower_components/angular/angular.js bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js
```

By the way this seems to be a solution to this type of problem, I hope this helps somebody in the future

Comment: Look at the order of the files: when you split it yourself, angular-route is above angular-resource, the automated one is after. Try see if there's an unterminated file or function there that might be breaking the file concatenation

Comment: I've tried to change the order of them, inserting angular, angular-resource and angular-route, the app is still working, I'm thinking that the problem is ** when trying to reach all the files in folder and subfolders

Comment: Do you have the ability to look at the output file? Sounds weird that ** is messing up like that, though I guess it is possible

Comment: I can see the output file but it have 40.000 and over lines, and searching for a ";"or a "," is hard, by the way, ** and i've tested the fact that the files are not compromised by changing the order, eveything works right

Comment: That's really odd, then. But guess you found a problem with that type of concatenation.

Comment: True, really strange beacuse with the application js files everything works perfectly, by the way the solution is to point each files inside folders directly, maybe there are some permissions problems